# Archlinux: obmenu won't start

Tags: gtk, gtk3, archlinux, gtk2

I'm on openbox at Arch Linux and recently installed my system.
I want to use `obmenu` to configure the menu.

But for some reason, it is not working.
Error at startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/obmenu", line 582, in <module>
    app.init()
  File "/usr/bin/obmenu", line 489, in init
    self.menu.loadMenu(self.menu_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/obxml.py", line 153, in loadMenu
    self.dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(fil.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1928, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
 xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 167, column 27
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please add answer to it. I'm deleting my own, because it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it. My menu contained an Formatting Mistake!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove

```
rm ~/.config/openbox/menu.xml
```

and then

```
cp /etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml ~/.config/openbox
```

after that obmenu will work.
Look at the http://obmenu.sourceforge.net/doc.html.
The problem is that you have menu.xml which does't have correct syntax. Evan empty file is wrong.